# So I am reading through a text and I am not sure if my translation of this sentence is correct

Tags: grammar, translation

The sentence in question is "困らせちゃだめよ?". I know that 困らせ is simply a causative form of 困る and that ちゃ is a feminine casual ては. I translated the sentence to "So you're not troubled anymore, are you?" I don't know why, but I've got the nagging feeling that the translation is incorrect.

Comment: Hint: 〜てはだめ is a variant of 〜てはいけない

Comment: Also, **context**.  Without any, accurate translation is often impossible.

Comment: しまった！http://www2.pegasusknight.com/wiki/fe14/index.php?%E4%BC%9A%E8%A9%B1%E9%9B%86%2F%E6%94%AF%E6%8F%B4%E4%BC%9A%E8%A9%B1%2F%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A6%E3%83%8B%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%28%E7%94%B7%E6%80%A7%E3%83%BB%E4%BF%BA%29%28%E8%A6%AA%E4%B8%96%E4%BB%A3%E3%83%BB%E6%9A%97%E5%A4%9C%29#ieb54ff7 (Scroll down to 支援S and read the last phrase by カミラ)

Comment: 私は自分の間違いをすまなく思っている.

Comment: ～ちゃ for ～ては isn't necessarily feminine, but some people do think it sounds childish.

Comment: Ah, ok, The more you know.

Answer (score 1):

“困らせちゃだめよ” is a colloquial turn of phrase for 困らせてはいけない、which means “You mustn’t trouble (somebody).” It’s an imperative form, and reverse to “You're not troubled.” Apparently it sounds feminine. A man would say "“困らせちゃだめ**だ**よ”

As I don’t know the context of the quoted phrase, I wonder why it’s trailed by a question mark.

Comment: You can use question marks for rising pitch even when it's not a question. I've seen よ？ all the time for a sort of girly 'you really ought to know this' kind of intonation.

Comment: ＠Sjiveru. The use of よ has nothing to do with question at all. It’s rather imperative in the nuance. Also it isn’t necessarily feminine in tone.
For instance, “よせよ – Stop it,” “早くやれよ – Do it quickly,” “バカ言うんじゃねえよ – Don’t talk rubbish,” “ふざけんなよ – It’s not a joke,” “舐めんなよ- Don’t make a fool of me” sound all muscular and imperative.

Comment: I'm talking about よ？ specifically, not just よ in general.

Comment: In fact, I don't understand why "?" is added to this phrase. But forget about it . It's not a big thing to me.

Comment: As Sjiveru said, I think this question mark was used to add the feeling of "..., okay?"